# AngularDart tour of heroes tutorial throws an error 'Hero' isn't a function?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

error: 'Hero' isn't a function. (invocation_of_non_function at [angular_dart_tour_of_heroes] lib\app_component.dart:18)

hero.dart

```
class Hero {
  final int id;
  String name;

  Hero(this.id, this.name);
}
```

app_component.dart

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/angular_components.dart';

import 'hero.dart';

@Component(
  selector: 'my-app',
  styleUrls: const ['app_component.css'],
  templateUrl: 'app_component.html',
  directives: const [materialDirectives,],
  providers: const [materialProviders],
)
class AppComponent {
  final title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  Hero hero = Hero(1, 'Windstorm');

}
```

app_component.html

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<h2>{{hero.name}}</h2>
<div><label>id: </label>{{hero.id}}</div>
<div><label>name: </label>{{hero.name}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are using a too old Dart version that still requires the now optional `new`

Comment: Dart VM version: 1.24.3 (Wed Dec 13 18:05:29 2017) on "windows_x64"

Comment: Angular 5 requires Dart 2. https://webdev.dartlang.org/tools/sdk#install shows how to install Dart 2 dev channel (no final available yet).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using a Angular 5 / Dart 2 version of the tutorial under Dart 1. Which version of the Dart SDK are you using? (Run: `dart --version`).

I'd suggest using **Angular 2 and Dart 2**.

If you want to use **Dart 1.24.3**, then you'll need the [Angular 4 version of the tutorial](https://webdev-angular4-dartlang-org.firebaseapp.com/angular/tutorial).

Comment: Dart VM version: 1.24.3 (Wed Dec 13 18:05:29 2017) on "windows_x64"

Comment: I've edited my answer to provide a link to the Angular 4 version of the tutorial. Use that version of the app sources if you want to keep working with Dart 1.24.3. But I'd recommend you use Angular 2 and Dart 2.